# Create disk container (like ISO) that can auto mount as RW

Tags: windows

Im looking for some windows program that can
 - create and mount large disk containers, like ISO files
 - must be read and writable
 - can be run as a daemon

Encryption is not needed. I suppose I could use truecrypt for this but the Encryption creates some overhead I dont need.

Edit, Im using windows 2008 Server R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mount a VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872416.aspx). You can use the GUI tools, or `diskpart` allows you to automate the effort:

```
DiskPart 
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7100 
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation. 
On computer: WIN7 
DISKPART> create vdisk file="C:\vdisks\disk1.vhd" maximum=16000 
DISKPART> attach vdisk 
DISKPART> create partition primary 
DISKPART> assign letter=g 
DISKPART> format
```

Note that it might be visible across all sessions on the computer, not limited to the service account.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows 7 (you don't specify) you can use VHD files, see [this Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, win2k8 R2